# Wire Gauge requirement for new bathroom fan install?

Tags: wiring

Just bought Panasonic FV-08-11VFL5E BAth fAN ,LIGHT AND NIGHT LIGHT. .THIS PIC IS IN THE INSTRUCTIONS.  ONE GREEN GROUND WIRE CONNECTED TO METAL BOX.  2 BLACK AND ONE WHITE WIRE FOR THE LIGHT AND NIGHT LIGHT SHARE ONE OF THOSE SMALL CONNECTOR BOXES THEN ALSO ANOTHER CONNECTION BOX WITH ONE BLACK AND ONE WHITE WIRE FOR VENT.   i BELIEVE i CAN HANDEL ALL THE WIRING ONCE i UNDERSTAND WHAT WIRE IS IN THE INCOMING CONDUIT. and from where?..3 BLACK 2 WHITE 1 GROUND? AND CAN THIS ALL BE DONE WITH EXISTING 14/2 LIGHT SWITCH. I can get a new wire from fixture to wall switch for more wires, but difficult to get all the way to breaker box

[image]

Comment: what wires are in your switch box (picture)?  What wires re at the fixture location (picture)?  You'll need three switches.

Comment: Please edit your text so it is not all in capitol letters, It is a pain to read. **All caps it the equivalent of yelling in a restaurant**, not necessary and very annoying.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes in question please?